# Iniciando con Java en Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, java-8, vscode

Señores buenos días, estoy intentando configurar Java para Visual Studio Code, con el fin de realizar todos mis proyectos con este editor de código, ya he instalado el JDK en su versión 8, tambien he instalado el Pack de Visual Studio Code con las extensiones de Java que se encuentra en la pagina oficial de Visual Studio Code, al parecer no tengo inconvenientes con la instalacion, mas sin embargo, al crear un nuevo proyecto Java en el editor, me pide Seleccionar un Tipo de Proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco me indiquen cual debo seleccionar o si quizás me falta algo por realizar para que me aparezca la ventana donde ubicaré la carpeta que contendrá mis proyectos, y posteriormente para darle nombre a mi proyecto.

Quedo atento a sus comentarios de ayuda por favor.

Comment: pues primero debes saber si es un proyecto swing o web o una consola, creo que si vas a programar solo sin ninguno framework de desarrollo como maven o spring boot utiliza el primero work with source code directly; pero para una mejor experiencia en programación java utiliza netbeans o eclipse.

Comment: @ger Muchísimas gracias, en realidad no sabia por cual iniciar, pero tu comentario me ayudo. Gracias... Lastima no lo pusiste como respuesta para poder cerrar esta pregunta como resuelta. Ya logré iniciar mi primer proyecto.

Comment: Lo colocare como respuesta entonces ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza el primero work with source code directly; pero para una mejor experiencia en programación java utiliza netbeans o eclipse

Comment: Gracias @ger ya tenia Netbeans, mas sin embargo lo quité ya que me recomendaron usar Visual Studio Code, al ser un editor de código me dijeron que va mucho mas rápido que el Netbeans. Ya quedó listo para seguir trabajando en mis proyectos, muchas gracias.